# How do I properly handle a .NET Core Web API input when a model property causes an integer overflow?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to determine the correct way to respond to an input from a user that results in an integer overflow. This is a contrived example, but exactly what we're facing. Consider this input model that will be received on a POST endpoint:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models {
  public class FavoriteNumberInputDto {


    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Number must be 0 or greater.")]
    public int FavoriteNumber { get; set;}
  }
}
```

So let's imagine the input body is this:

```
{
   "name":"Bob",
   "favoriteNumber":123456789012345
}
```

The response looks something like this:

```
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
   "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
   "status":400,
   "traceId":"00-25560820e32e65d9430fabb2d760f122-cfdf87e22cfbbd65-00",
   "errors":{
      "favoriteNumberInputDto":[
         "The favoriteNumberInputDto field is required."
      ],
      "$.favoriteNumber":[
         "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.favoriteNumber| LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 35."
      ]
   }
}
```

The input model is null due to a deserialization error (int overflow). And then a required error is thrown for the entire input model, not the individual property.

We will have a UI that has form input validation, so while this is likely not a real scenario, would you handle this type of error specifically? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything to handle the issue -- the underlying implementation is already giving a perfectly reasonable HTTP 400 response with plenty of information describing the problem. 

Your UI should be able to handle that response when making the API call and act accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.T That is my opinion. But now I'm looking at multiple bugs added to our board for this issue and I've never thought about it before. And I guess I was looking more for a sanity check. I assume if I wanted a better message (such as "The number you entered was too large") then I assume I'd have to do some custom deserialization work.

Comment: I dont use validation much but should this not  - or - show the json parse error or fail on the validator? This looks like the conversion fails, hence because of this the value is 0 and hence the validation also fails. meaning validation fails because of an parse error, not because the validation was invalid.

Comment: @sommmen The validation on the int property is never hit because the API input body fails to deserialize into the target model. It is indeed a parse error, not a validation error, and I'm curious of others handle this scenario specifically.

Comment: you need to validate on the front-end.  (in the GUI but also before you send the request... if you don't want to prevent the whole request you could deal with it then)  You could also change the type to a string.  What is this value used for?

Comment: I'd say parse errors are programming errors and i'd classify them as such -  you'd either need to use a long and check the range if its common to input higher number values and you want nice validation, or i'd let it crash as-is, and then your frontend app should just never send you invalid non-parseable data. You can think of this in a couple ways so i'd just find the best fit for your case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no need to write a custom validation to do this thing.

You could just modify the error message to mention this thing.

```
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = $@"Number must be more than 0 and less than 2147483647")]
```

Besides, if you still want to show the error message based on different condition, I suggest you could consider writing the custom  validation as this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-attributes) shows.

Comment: In the case where a number input is provided that exceeds int.MaxValue, this validation is never hit and the error message will not be returned. The model containing this property fails to serialize and is null. You get the exact type of error response I posted.